# using layout view inside gallery

Tags: android

I am using Gallery and put a layout inside each item.
I have 3 views and each of them about 15 imageviews .
But my gallery works so slow.
Is there anyone who are using views inside gallery

Answer (score 0):

Double check the size of your images in the image views. If they are too large that can effect performance.

I'm not sure if it applies but look into hardware acceleration if you're using a high enough SDK level.

Comment: image size are not large, also i tried to build api level 7-8-10-11 but results are same. What should I focus to if i put a view inside gallery

Comment: I posted my code to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606355/layout-like-gallery could you please check?